# Stream chat react : how to remove file upload button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, stream, chat

I'm using stream chat react v-6.11.0 now i want to remove attachment file button from the message box please consider  [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF6Q4.png)   for more details

have googled a lot but no luck , major suggestions are related to react native for same package which are not working with we version,thanks in advance